# Suggested framework for web application that will give users directions

Tags: php, web-applications, dijkstra

I'm starting to work on a web application that will utilize Dijkstra's algorithm to find users the fastest directions for point A to point B. I'm just wondering if anyone has any suggestions for a framework for this? I was leaning towards something involving PHP, but I'd really prefer to not build my own framework as that seems overkill.

I'm only being given some images to work with, does anyone have suggestions for how I'd draw a line from point A to point B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you're really looking for a PHP framework (like CodeIgniter or Symfony) or just for PHP library for image manipulation. Framework are useful to manage your whole application, dealing with users management, permission, data storage, etc... If your looking to just manipulate images, a Library should do the thing.

My first app I did to manage a map was in plain PHP using the GD library (usually installed with your version of PHP). Documentation available here : http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Quick small example to draw a line on an existing picture with GD :

```
// Create image from existing jpg
$image = @imagecreatefromjpeg('map.jpg');
// Draw a red line from X1 = 10, Y1 = 10, X2 = 20, Y2 = 20
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);
imageline($image , 10 , 10 , 20 , 20 , $red);
```

You can do a lot of things with GD, it just takes time to be used to.

Comment: Interesting, that makes sense. So if I were to implement the user/administration part (framework) I just use the library on that part of the application under whatever framework I use?

Comment: The choice of a framework depends on what you expect for your application. GD is just a tool and can do lot of things, but it's very low level, you will have to build your own class based on this to do what you want from your app. To my knowledge there is no PHP framework dedicated to the creation of maps or image manipulation, so I recommend you to start with a flexible one, that gives you more freedom in your coding. I don't know if you're new to the framework concept, but depending of your level, some are tougher than other to learn, also I don't have enough information on your...

Comment: .. application to recommend you one. If you have no experience, I'll tell you start with CodeIgniter for instance, I personally found this one easier to learn than Symfony, but again you need to know what you want from your application. A framework will not automatically generate your app, it'll just give you a structure to develop your project and deal with the common tasks related to web development. I don't know if I'm very clear in my answer or if it helps you, so to answer your last question : Yes you can use GD with whatever PHP framework you go with :).

Comment: One last thing, I don't know anything of your project, but if you're dealing with maps, have a look to the Javascript Google Maps API, for instance, how to draw a line on a map : http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines

Comment: Well mostly I've worked pretty high level on projects that need bug fixing and some customization so this from-the-beginning is pretty new to me. I've taken a look at the google maps API and the only problem is that I have maps which are inside of buildings and around a few buildings. I'll probably start with the main function of the application and run with that before I move into incorporating a framework, really I just want the map/direction system to function first.